# How to demonstrate a limit without having to pre-calculate certain points

Tags: graphics

1. You have a circle of radius r centered at the origin.
2. You have a circle of radius 1 centered at (1,0).
3. You draw a ray through the point (0,r) and the point where the circles intersect.
4. Let R be the point where the ray intersects the x-axis.
5. The question is, what happens to the point R as $r\to 0$.

I have:

```
Manipulate[
  Graphics[{
    Circle[{1, 0}, 1],
    Circle[{0, 0}, r],
    Red, PointSize[Medium],
    Point[{0, r}],
    Point[{r^2/2, Sqrt[1 - (r^2/2 - 1)^2]}],
    Point[{2 + Sqrt[4 - r^2], 0}],
    HalfLine[{{0, r}, {r^2/2, Sqrt[1 - (r^2/2 - 1)^2]}}]},
    Axes -> True,
    PlotRange -> {{-2, 5}, {-2, 2}}], 
  {{r, 1.4}, 0, 1.5}]
```

Which produces this image.

[image]

Now, I did a bunch of math, similar triangles, etc., to find that the coordinates of the point of intersection is $(r^2/2,\sqrt{1-(r^2/2-1)^2}$ and the point R, where the ray intersects the x-axis, is $2+\sqrt{4-r^2}$.

I'm just wondering how folks might do this same thing without making those math calculations.

Comment: Perhaps you could use the new geometric region functions? For instance, the intersection point between the two circles could be represented as `RegionIntersection[Circle[{1, 0}, 1], Circle[{0, 0}, r], HalfPlane[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, {0, 1}]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example using **geometrical region functions**:

```
Manipulate[

 pointoncircle = RegionIntersection[
    Circle[{0, 0}, r],
    Circle[{1, 0}, 1],
    HalfPlane[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, {1, 1}]
  ];
 ray = HalfLine[{{0, r}, pointoncircle[[1]]}];
 pointonaxis = RegionIntersection[ray, InfiniteLine[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]];

 Graphics[{
   Circle[{0, 0}, r], Circle[{1, 0}, 1],
   Red, PointSize[Large],
   Point[{0, r}], pointoncircle, ray, pointonaxis
  },
  Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-2, 5}, {-2, 2}}
 ],

 {{r, 1.4}, 0.001, 1.5}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Of course an alternative approach would be to **set up appropriate equations** describing the points you need, then letting *Mathematica* do the solving:

```
pointoncircle = Point[{x, y}] /. First@
   NSolve[{x^2 + y^2 == r^2, (x - 1)^2 + y^2 == 1, y >= 0}, {x, y}];

ray = HalfLine[{{0, r}, pointoncircle[[1]]}];

pointonaxis = Point[{x, 0} /. First@
    Solve[InterpolatingPolynomial[{{0, r}, pointoncircle[[1]]}, x] == 0, x]];
```

These definitions can be plugged into the `Manipulate` shown above with identical results.

Comment: An extremely well written answer. Thanks so much.